Indy SMTP for hotmail with app password and two step verification
Since some days Indy TIdSMTP can no longer send email from my program from a Hotmail account throwing the error Authentication unsuccessful Basic authentication is disabled.
I activated two-step verification and generated an app password replacing the old password in code without changing any other setting used before but the same error.
I use smtp-mail.outlook.com/587 for host/port config and the following code :
  SMTP.Username := cbxFrom.Text;
  SMTP.Password := pwd;
  SMTP.Host := 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
  SMTP.Port := 587;
  SMTP.Connect;

It fails on :
  SMTP.Send(msg);

Same problem with TIdImap4.
Any example of how to send or receive to/from Hotmail using two-step and app password?

As of September 16th 2024, you have to now use OAuth2 authentication with Microsoft.
Modern Authentication Methods now needed to continue syncing Outlook Email in non-Microsoft email apps
You can take a look at Geoff Smith's code which uses SMTP with XOAUTH2:
https://github.com/geoffsmith82/GmailAuthSMTP
It means that it can be integrated with existing Indy code, but yeah.. there are also REST APIs.

FYI, Indy's own SASL OAuth components (including XOAUTH2) were merged into Indy's master code earlier today, see the announcement on Indy's blog: SASL OAuth support finally added to master

I just see Remy added support in Indy : Thanks a lot for this :)

Any simple example of using SASL with Indy? but with no Rest components as I am interested in Delphi 2007..

I also recently find sgcIndy that implement OAuth for Indy https://www.esegece.com/products/sgcindy/features-overview
